# Apply a stream of mappers to another stream in Java8

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, java-stream

In Java8 I have a stream and I want to apply a *stream of mappers*.

For example:

```
Stream<String> strings = Stream.of("hello", "world");
Stream<Function<String, String>> mappers = Stream.of(t -> t+"?", t -> t+"!", t -> t+"?");
```

I want to write:

```
strings.map(mappers); // not working
```

But my current best way of solving my task is:

```
for (Function<String, String> mapper : mappers.collect(Collectors.toList()))
    strings = strings.map(mapper);

strings.forEach(System.out::println);
```

How can I solve this problem

- without collecting the mappers into a list
- without using a `for` loop
- without breaking my fluent code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since `map` requires a function that can be applied to each element, but your `Stream<Function<…>>` can only be evaluated a single time, it is unavoidable to process the stream to something reusable. If it shouldn’t be a `Collection`, just reduce it to a single `Function`:

```
strings.map(mappers.reduce(Function::andThen).orElse(Function.identity()))
```

Complete example:

```
Stream<Function<String, String>> mappers = Stream.of(t -> t+"?", t -> t+"!", t -> t+"?");
Stream.of("hello", "world")
      .map(mappers.reduce(Function::andThen).orElse(Function.identity()))
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Other variations that work: `mappers.reduce(Function.identity(), Function::andThen)`, `mappers.reduce(Function.identity(), Function::compose)`.

Comment: @rgettman: the `orElse` variant is a small optimization as it doesn’t combine an identity function with another function.

Comment: It would be nice if `Function.identity()` overrode `compose` and `andThen`… Or maybe the JIT compiler would get rid of this complexity anyway?

Comment: @Didier L: such override would be nice, but then it couldn’t get implemented as the simple lambda expression `t->t` anymore. When it comes to CPU complexity, the JIT *does* optimize away such things if the function becomes a hot spot. Then, only a small additional memory allocation remains (unless Escape Analysis can prove that it’s a purely local thing). That’s why I said, it’s a *small* optimization.